# Could not get to load Page on spring mvc with maven and Apache server

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a Spring application with maven and trying to run that on Apache Server through Eclipse. Server executes perfectly but i am not able to access webpages. Loading a page results in 404.

**SpringBootApplicationStarter.java**

```
package com.archit;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApplicationStarter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplicationStarter.class, args);  
    }  
}
```

**MyWebAppInitializer.java**

```
package com.archit.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyWebAppInitializer extends 
   AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[]{RootConfig.class};
   }

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[]{"/*"};
   }
}
```

**RootConfig.java**

```
package com.archit.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class RootConfig {
   //Service and Repository beans configuration
   //....
}
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
package com.archit.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "com.archit.controller" })
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                        .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

   @Bean
   public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
      InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
      resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/jsp/");
      resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
      return resolver;
   }

}
```

**LandingController.java**

```
package com.archit.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class LandingController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getLandingPage(Model model) {
        return "landing";
    }

}
```

**landing.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    I'm Landing Page
</body>
</html>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.archit</groupId>
  <artifactId>MarketplaceWebUI</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MarketplaceWebUI Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>  
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>  
    <spring.version>5.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-boot.version>1.5.10.RELEASE</spring-boot.version> 
  </properties>  
  <parent>  
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>  
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>  
  </parent>  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>  
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>      
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>  
        <version>${spring.version}</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>  
        <version>${spring.version}</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>  
        <version>${spring.version}</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>  
        <version>${spring.version}</version>  
    </dependency>  
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>MarketplaceWebUI</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

File structure looks like the image provided below
[image: File Structure]

Comment: What do you mean by running on `Apache Server ...` ? This is a spring boot app you can just start the jar file or via `mvn spring-boot:run`?

Comment: @architjn Which version spring boot your using? Can also post your application.properties file here.

Comment: I don't know much, but i want to run through eclipse so that i can execute project in debug mode, and i think that would not be possible in case of mvn command

Comment: @DipakThoke I don't have any

Comment: Can add spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp in your application.properties file which present into resource folder

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>   this into pox.xml and try to update the project

Comment: @DipakThoke i did that prefix and suffix in WebConfig.java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165361/discussion-between-dipak-thoke-and-architjn).

Comment: <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency> add this dependency into your pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this dependency because

Example : How To configure

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-boot/spring-boot-jsp-view-example/

**Note: Why this dependency  Required**

We want to use JSP as the view. Default embedded servlet container for Spring Boot Starter Web is tomcat. To enable support for JSP’s, we would need to add a dependency on tomcat-embed-jasper.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Run your Project as Java Aplication from eclispe